# option_value of wp_options is too long

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I claim to the server provider that my site is running too slow. They said that it is because of the site development problem and they sent me a report which says that it takes more than 40 seconds to update wp_options table.
Here is one of those.

```
 2. Executed 22h 11m 24s ago for 52.135218 sec on Database --> p*****ip_db                                                                                                  
Date: 2016-03-19 00:08:20 Query_time: 52.135218 Rows_examined: 1: Rows_sent 0 Lock_time: 0.000359                                                                           
# Schema: pi****p_db  Last_errno: 0  Killed: 0 UPDATE `wp_options` SET `option_value` = 'a:19:{s:13:\"administrator\";a:2:{s:4:\"name\";s:13:\"Administrator\";s:12:\"capabilities\";a:215:{s:13:\"switch_themes\";b:1;s:11:\"edit_themes\";b:1;s:16:\"activate_plugins\";b:1;s:12:\"edit_plugins\";b:1;s:10:\"edit_users\";b:1;s:10:\"edit_files\";b:1;s:14:\"manage_options\";b:1;s:17:\"moderate_comments\";b:1;s:17:\"manage_categories\";b:1;s:12:\"manage_links\";b:1;s:12:\"upload_files\";b:1;s:6:\"import\";b:1;s:15:\"unfiltered_html\";b:1;s:10:\"edit_posts\";b:1;s:17:\"edit_others_posts\";b:1;s:20:\"edit_published_posts\";b:1;s:13:\"publish_posts\";b:1;s:10:\"edit_pages\";b:1;s:4:\"read\";b:1;s:8:\"level_10\";b:1;s:7:\"level_9\";b:1;s:7:\"level_8\";b:1;s:7:\"level_7\";b:1;s:7:\"level_6\";b:1;s:7:\"level_5\";b:1;s:7:\"level_4\";b:1;s:7:\"level_3\";b:1;s:7:\"level_2\";b:1;s:7:\"level_1\";b:1;s:7:\"level_0\";b:1;s:17:\"edit_others_pages\";b:1;s:20:\"edit_published_pages\";b:1;s:13:\"publish_pages\";b:1;s:12:\"delete_pages\";b:1;s:19:\"delete_others_pages\";b:1;s:22:\"delete_published_pages\";b:1;s:12:\"delete_posts\";b:1;s:19:\"delete_others_posts\";b:1;s:22:\"delete_published_posts\";b:1;s:20:\"delete_private_posts\";b:1;s:18:\"edit_private_posts\";b:1;s:18:\"read_private_posts\";b:1;s:20:\"delete_private_pages\";b:1;s:18:\"edit_private_pages\";b:1;s:18:\"read_private_pages\";b:1;s:12:\"delete_users\";b:1;s:12:\"create_users\";b:1;s:17:\"unfiltered_upload\";b:1;s:14:\"edit_dashboard\";b:1;s:14:\"update_plugins\";b:1;s:14:\"delete_plugins\";b:1;s:15:\"install_plugins\";b:1;s:13:\"update_themes\";b:1;s:14:\"install_themes\";b:1;s:11:\"update_core\";b:1;s:10:\"list_users\";b:1;s:12:\"remove_users\";b:1;s:13:\"promote_users\";b:1;s:18:\"edit_theme_options\";b:1;s:13:\"delete_themes\";b:1;s:6:\"export\";b:1;s:23:\"gravityview_full_access\";b:1;s:25:\"gravityview_view_settings\";b:1;s:25:\"gravityview_edit_settings\";b:1;s:21:\"gravityview_uninstall\";b:1;s:27:\"gravityview_contact_support\";b:1;s:24:\"edit_others_gravityviews\";b:1;s:25:\"read_private_gravityviews\";b:1;s:27:\"delete_private_gravityviews\";b:1;s:26:\"delete_others_gravityviews\";b:1;s:25:\"edit_private_gravityviews\";b:1;s:20:\"publish_gravityviews\";b:1;s:29:\"delete_published_gravityviews\";b:1;s:27:\"edit_published_gravityviews\";b:1;s:17:\"copy_gravityviews\";b:1;s:31:\"gravityview_edit_others_entries\";b:1;s:35:\"gravityview_view_others_entry_notes\";b:1;s:35:\"gravityview_edit_others_entry_notes\";b:1;s:28:\"gravityview_moderate_entries\";b:1;s:33:\"gravityview_delete_others_entries\";b:1;s:24:\"gravityview_edit_entries\";b:1;s:22:\"gravityview_edit_entry\";b:1;s:29:\"gravityview_edit_form_entries\";b:1;s:28:\"gravityview_view_entry_notes\";b:1;s:26:\"gravityview_delete_entries\";b:1;s:24:\"gravityview_delete_entry\";b:1;s:17:\"edit_gravityviews\";b:1;s:19:\"delete_gravityviews\";b:1;s:27:\"gravityview_getting_started\";b:1;s:24:\"gravityview_support_port\";b:1;s:24:\"gravityview_view_entries\";b:1;s:31:\"gravityview_view_others_entries\";b:1;s:17:\"view_shop_reports\";b:1;s:24:\"view_shop_sensitive_data\";b:1;s:19:\"export_shop_reports\";b:1;s:21:\"manage_shop_discounts\";b:1;s:20:\"manage_shop_settings\";b:1;s:12:\"edit_product\";b:1;s:12:\"read_product\";b:1;s:14:\"delete_product\";b:1;s:13:\"edit_products\";b:1;s:20:\"edit_others_products\";b:1;s:16:\"publish_products\";b:1;s:21:\"read_private_products\";b:1;s:15:\"delete_products\";b:1;s:23:\"delete_private_products\";b:1;s:25:\"delete_published_products\";b:1;s:22:\"delete_others_products\";b:1;s:21:\"edit_private_products\";b:1;s:23:\"edit_published_products\";b:1;s:20:\"manage_product_terms\";b:1;s:18:\"edit_product_terms\";b:1;s:20:\"delete_product_terms\";b:1;s:20:\"assign_product_terms\";b:1;s:18:\"view_product_stats\";b:1;s:17:\"edit_shop_payment\";b:1;s:17:\"read_shop_payment\";b:1;s:19:\"delete_shop_payment\";b:1;s:18:\"edit_shop_payments\";b:1;s:25:\"edit_others_shop_payments\";b:1;s:21:\"publish_shop_payments\";b:1;s:26:\"read_private_shop_payments\";b:1;s:20:\"delete_shop_payments\";b:1;s:28:\"delete_private_shop_payments\";b:1;s:30:\"delete_published_shop_payments\";b:1;s:27:\"delete_others_shop_payments\";b:1;s:26:\"edit_private_shop_payments\";b:1;s:28:\"edit_published_shop_payments\";b:1;s:25:\"manage_shop_payment_terms\";b:1;s:23:\"edit_shop_payment_terms\";b:1;s:25:\"delete_shop_payment_terms\";b:1;s:25:\"assign_shop_payment_terms\";b:1;s:23:\"view_shop_payment_stats\";b:1;s:18:\"edit_shop_discount\";b:1;s:18:\"read_shop_discount\";b:1;s:20:\"delete_shop_discount\";b:1;s:19:\"edit_shop_discounts\";b:1;s:26:\"edit_others_shop_discounts\";b:1;s:22:\"publish_shop_discounts\";b:1;s:27:\"read_private_shop_discounts\";b:1;s:21:\"delete_shop_discounts\";b:1;s:29:\"delete_private_shop_discounts\";b:1;s:31:\"delete_published_shop_discounts\";b:1;s:28:\"delete_others_shop_discounts\";b:1;s:27:\"edit_private_shop_discounts\";b:1;s:29:\"edit_published_shop_discounts\";b:1;s:26:\"manage_shop_discount_terms\";b:1;s:24:\"edit_shop_discount_terms\";b:1;s:26:\"delete_shop_discount_terms\";b:1;s:26:\"assign_shop_discount_terms\";b:1;s:24:\"view_shop_discount_stats\";b:1;s:12:\"fes_is_admin\";b:1;s:10:\"list_roles\";b:1;s:12:\"create_roles\";b:1;s:12:\"delete_roles\";b:1;s:10:\"edit_roles\";b:1;s:16:\"restrict_content\";b:1;s:18:\"manage_woocommerce\";b:1;s:24:\"view_woocommerce_reports\";b:1;s:15:\"edit_shop_order\";b:1;s:15:\"read_shop_order\";b:1;s:17:\"delete_shop_order\";b:1;s:16:\"edit_shop_orders\";b:1;s:23:\"edit_others_shop_orders\";b:1;s:19:\"publish_shop_orders\";b:1;s:24:\"read_private_shop_orders\";b:1;s:18:\"delete_shop_orders\";b:1;s:26:\"delete_private_shop_orders\";b:1;s:28:\"delete_published_shop_orders\";b:1;s:25:\"delete_others_shop_orders\";b:1;s:24:\"edit_private_shop_orders\";b:1;s:26:\"edit_published_shop_orders\";b:1;s:23:\"manage_shop_order_terms\";b:1;s:21:\"edit_shop_order_terms\";b:1;s:23:\"delete_shop_order_terms\";b:1;s:23:\"assign_shop_order_terms\";b:1;s:16:\"edit_shop_coupon\";b:1;s:16:\"read_shop_coupon\";b:1;s:18:\"delete_shop_coupon\";b:1;s:17:\"edit_shop_coupons\";b:1;s:24:\"edit_others_shop_coupons\";b:1;s:20:\"publish_shop_coupons\";b:1;s:25:\"read_private_shop_coupons\";b:1;s:19:\"delete_shop_coupons\";b:1;s:27:\"delete_private_shop_coupons\";b:1;s:29:\"delete_published_shop_coupons\";b:1;s:26:\"delete_others_shop_coupons\";b:1;s:25:\"edit_private_shop_coupons\";b:1;s:27:\"edit_published_shop_coupons\";b:1;s:24:\"manage_shop_coupon_terms\";b:1;s:22:\"edit_shop_coupon_terms\";b:1;s:24:\"delete_shop_coupon_terms\";b:1;s:24:\"assign_shop_coupon_terms\";b:1;s:17:\"edit_shop_webhook\";b:1;s:17:\"read_shop_webhook\";b:1;s:19:\"delete_shop_webhook\";b:1;s:18:\"edit_shop_webhooks\";b:1;s:25:\"edit_others_shop_webhooks\";b:1;s:21:\"publish_shop_webhooks\";b:1;s:26:\"read_private_shop_webhooks\";b:1;s:20:\"delete_shop_webhooks\";b:1;s:28:\"delete_private_shop_webhooks\";b:1;s:30:\"delete_published_shop_webhooks\";b:1;s:27:\"delete_others_shop_webhooks\";b:1;s:26:\"edit_private_shop_webhooks\";b:1;s:28:\"edit_published_shop_webhooks\";b:1;s:25:\"manage_shop_webhook_terms\";b:1;s:23:\"edit_shop_webhook_terms\";b:1;s:25:\"delete_shop_webhook_terms\";b:1;s:25:\"assign_shop_webhook_terms\";b:1;s:19:\"manage_capabilities\";b:1;s:18:\"email_users_notify\";b:1;s:17:\"email_single_user\";b:1;s:20:\"email_multiple_users\";b:1;s:17:\"email_user_groups\";b:1;}}s:6:\"editor\";a:2:{s:4:\"name\";s:6:\"Editor\";s:12:\"capabilities\";a:65:{s:17:\"moderate_comments\";b:1;s:17:\"manage_categories\";b:1;s:12:\"manage_links\";b:1;s:12:\"upload_files\";b:1;s:15:\"unfiltered_html\";b:1;s:10:\"edit_posts\";b:1;s:17:\"edit_others_posts\";b:1;s:20:\"edit_published_posts\";b:1;s:13:\"publish_posts\";b:1;s:10:\"edit_pages\";b:1;s:4:\"read\";b:1;s:7:\"level_7\";b:1;s:7:\"level_6\";b:1;s:7:\"level_5\";b:1;s:7:\"level_4\";b:1;s:7:\"level_3\";b:1;s:7:\"level_2\";b:1;s:7:\"level_1\";b:1;s:7:\"level_0\";b:1;s:17:\"edit_others_pages\";b:1;s:20:\"edit_published_pages\";b:1;s:13:\"publish_pages\";b:1;s:12:\"delete_pages\";b:1;s:19:\"delete_others_pages\";b:1;s:22:\"delete_published_pages\";b:1;s:12:\"delete_posts\";b:1;s:19:\"delete_others_posts\";b:1;s:22:\"delete_published_posts\";b:1;s:20:\"delete_private_posts\";b:1;s:18:\"edit_private_posts\";b:1;s:18:\"read_private_posts\";b:1;s:20:\"delete_private_pages\";b:1;s:18:\"edit_private_pages\";b:1;s:18:\"read_private_pages\";b:1;s:24:\"edit_others_gravityviews\";b:1;s:25:\"read_private_gravityviews\";b:1;s:27:\"delete_private_gravityviews\";b:1;s:26:\"delete_others_gravityviews\";b:1;s:25:\"edit_private_gravityviews\";b:1;s:20:\"publish_gravityviews\";b:1;s:29:\"delete_published_gravityviews\";b:1;s:27:\"edit_published_gravityviews\";b:1;s:17:\"copy_gravityviews\";b:1;s:31:\"gravityview_edit_others_entries\";b:1;s:35:\"gravityview_view_others_entry_notes\";b:1;s:35:\"gravityview_edit_others_entry_notes\";b:1;s:28:\"gravityview_moderate_entries\";b:1;s:33:\"gravityview_delete_others_entries\";b:1;s:24:\"gravityview_edit_entries\";b:1;s:22:\"gravityview_edit_entry\";b:1;s:29:\"gravityview_edit_form_entries\";b:1;s:28:\"gravityview_view_entry_notes\";b:1;s:26:\"gravityview_delete_entries\";b:1;s:24:\"gravityview_delete_entry\";b:1;s:17:\"edit_gravityviews\";b:1;s:19:\"delete_gravityviews\";b:1;s:27:\"gravityview_getting_started\";b:1;s:24:\"gravityview_support_port\";b:1;s:24:\"gravityview_view_entries\";b:1;s:31:\"gravityview_view_others_entries\";b:1;s:12:\"fes_is_admin\";b:1;s:18:\"email_users_notify\";b:1;s:17:\"email_single_user\";b:1;s:20:\"email_multiple_users\";b:1;s:17:\"email_user_groups\";b:1;}}s:6:\"author\";a:2:{s:4:\"name\";s:6:\"Author\";s:12:\"capabilities\";a:24:{s:12:\"upload_files\";b:1;s:10:\"edit_posts\";b:1;s:20:\"edit_published_posts\";b:1;s:13:\"publish_posts\";b:1;s:4:\"read\";b:1;s:7:\"level_2\";b:1;s:7:\"level_1\";b:1;s:7:\"level_0\";b:1;s:12:\"delete_posts\";b:1;s:22:\"delete_published_posts\";b:1;s:24:\"gravityview_edit_entries\";b:1;s:22:\"gravityview_edit_entry\";b:1;s:29:\"gravityview_edit_form_entries\";b:1;s:28:\"gravityview_view_entry_notes\";b:1;s:26:\"gravityview_delete_entries\";b:1;s:24:\"gravityview_delete_entry\";b:1;s:17:\"edit_gravityviews\";b:1;s:19:\"delete_gravityviews\";b:1;s:27:\"gravityview_getting_started\";b:1;s:24:\"gravityview_support_port\";b:1;s:24:\"gravityview_view_entries\";b:1;s:31:\"gravityview_view_others_entries\";b:1;s:17:\"email_single_user\";b:1;s:20:\"email_multiple_users\";b:1;}}s:11:\"contributor\";a:2:{s:4:\"name\";s:11:\"Contributor\";s:12:\"capabilities\";a:12:{s:10:\"edit_posts\";b:1;s:4:\"read\";b:1;s:7:\"level_1\";b:1;s:7:\"level_0\";b:1;s:12:\"delete_posts\";b:1;s:17:\"edit_gravityviews\";b:1;s:19:\"delete_gravityviews\";b:1;s:27:\"gravityview_getting_started\";b:1;s:24:\"gravityview_support_port\";b:1;s:24:\"gravityview_view_entries\";b:1;s:31:\"gravityview_view_others_entries\";b:1;s:17:\"email_single_user\";b:1;}}s:10:\"subscriber\";a:2:{s:4:\"name\";s:10:\"Subscriber\";s:12:\"capabilities\";a:4:{s:4:\"read\";b:1;s:7:\"level_0\";b:1;s:24:\"gravityview_view_entries\";b:1;s:31:\"gravityview_view_others_entries\";b:1;}}s:12:\"shop_manager\";a:2:{s:4:\"name\";s:12:\"Shop Manager\";s:12:\"capabilities\";a:140:{s:4:\"read\";b:1;s:10:\"edit_posts\";b:1;s:12:\"delete_posts\";b:1;s:15:\"unfiltered_html\";b:1;s:12:\"upload_files\";b:1;s:6:\"export\";b:1;s:6:\"import\";b:1;s:19:\"delete_others_pages\";b:1;s:19:\"delete_others_posts\";b:1;s:12:\"delete_pages\";b:1;s:20:\"delete_private_pages\";b:1;s:20:\"delete_private_posts\";b:1;s:22:\"delete_published_pages\";b:1;s:22:\"delete_published_posts\";b:1;s:17:\"edit_others_pages\";b:1;s:17:\"edit_others_posts\";b:1;s:10:\"edit_pages\";b:1;s:18:\"edit_private_pages\";b:1;s:18:\"edit_private_posts\";b:1;s:20:\"edit_published_pages\";b:1;s:20:\"edit_published_posts\";b:1;s:17:\"manage_categories\";b:1;s:12:\"manage_links\";b:1;s:17:\"moderate_comments\";b:1;s:13:\"publish_pages\";b:1;s:13:\"publish_posts\";b:1;s:18:\"read_private_pages\";b:1;s:18:\"read_private_posts\";b:1;s:17:\"view_shop_reports\";b:1;s:24:\"view_shop_sensitive_data\";b:1;s:19:\"export_shop_reports\";b:1;s:20:\"manage_shop_settings\";b:1;s:21:\"manage_shop_discounts\";b:1;s:12:\"edit_product\";b:1;s:12:\"read_product\";b:1;s:14:\"delete_product\";b:1;s:13:\"edit_products\";b:1;s:20:\"edit_others_products\";b:1;s:16:\"publish_products\";b:1;s:21:\"read_private_products\";b:1;s:15:\"delete_products\";b:1;s:23:\"delete_private_products\";b:1;s:25:\"delete_published_products\";b:1;s:22:\"delete_others_products\";b:1;s:21:\"edit_private_products\";b:1;s:23:\"edit_published_products\";b:1;s:20:\"manage_product_terms\";b:1;s:18:\"edit_product_terms\";b:1;s:20:\"delete_product_terms\";b:1;s:20:\"assign_product_terms\";b:1;s:18:\"view_product_stats\";b:1;s:17:\"edit_shop_payment\";b:1;s:17:\"read_shop_payment\";b:1;s:19:\"delete_shop_payment\";b:1;s:18:\"edit_shop_payments\";b:1;s:25:\"edit_others_shop_payments\";b:1;s:21:\"publish_shop_payments\";b:1;s:26:\"read_private_shop_payments\";b:1;s:20:\"delete_shop_payments\";b:1;s:28:\"delete_private_shop_payments\";b:1;s:30:\"delete_published_shop_payments\";b:1;s:27:\"delete_others_shop_payments\";b:1;s:26:\"edit_private_shop_payments\";b:1;s:28:\"edit_published_shop_payments\";b:1;s:25:\"manage_shop_payment_terms\";b:1;s:23:\"edit_shop_payment_terms\";b:1;s:25:\"delete_shop_payment_terms\";b:1;s:25:\"assign_shop_payment_terms\";b:1;s:23:\"view_shop_payment_stats\";b:1;s:18:\"edit_shop_discount\";b:1;s:18:\"read_shop_discount\";b:1;s:20:\"delete_shop_discount\";b:1;s:19:\"edit_shop_discounts\";b:1;s:26:\"edit_others_shop_discounts\";b:1;s:22:\"publish_shop_discounts\";b:1;s:27:\"read_private_shop_discounts\";b:1;s:21:\"delete_shop_discounts\";b:1;s:29:\"delete_private_shop_discounts\";b:1;s:31:\"delete_published_shop_discounts\";b:1;s:28:\"delete_others_shop_discounts\";b:1;s:27:\"edit_private_shop_discounts\";b:1;s:29:\"edit_published_shop_discounts\";b:1;s:26:\"manage_shop_discount_terms\";b:1;s:24:\"edit_shop_discount_terms\";b:1;s:26:\"delete_shop_discount_terms\";b:1;s:26:\"assign_shop_discount_terms\";b:1;s:24:\"view_shop_discount_stats\";b:1;s:18:\"manage_woocommerce\";b:1;s:24:\"view_woocommerce_reports\";b:1;s:15:\"edit_shop_order\";b:1;s:15:\"read_shop_order\";b:1;s:17:\"delete_shop_order\";b:1;s:16:\"edit_shop_orders\";b:1;s:23:\"edit_others_shop_orders\";b:1;s:19:\"publish_shop_orders\";b:1;s:24:\"read_private_shop_orders\";b:1;s:18:\"delete_shop_orders\";b:1;s:26:\"delete_private_shop_orders\";b:1;s:28:\"delete_published_shop_orders\";b:1;s:25:\"delete_others_shop_orders\";b:1;s:24:\"edit_private_shop_orders\";b:1;s:26:\"edit_published_shop_orders\";b:1;s:23:\"manage_shop_order_terms\";b:1;s:21:\"edit_shop_order_terms\";b:1;s:23:\"delete_shop_order_terms\";b:1;s:23:\"assign_shop_order_terms\";b:1;s:16:\"edit_shop_coupon\";b:1;s:16:\"read_shop_coupon\";b:1;s:18:\"delete_shop_coupon\";b:1;s:17:\"edit_shop_coupons\";b:1;s:24:\"edit_others_shop_coupons\";b:1;s:20:\"publish_shop_coupons\";b:1;s:25:\"read_private_shop_coupons\";b:1;s:19:\"delete_shop_coupons\";b:1;s:27:\"delete_private_shop_coupons\";b:1;s:29:\"delete_published_shop_coupons\";b:1;s:26:\"delete_others_shop_coupons\";b:1;s:25:\"edit_private_shop_coupons\";b:1;s:27:\"edit_published_shop_coupons\";b:1;s:24:\"manage_shop_coupon_terms\";b:1;s:22:\"edit_shop_coupon_terms\";b:1;s:24:\"delete_shop_coupon_terms\";b:1;s:24:\"assign_shop_coupon_terms\";b:1;s:17:\"edit_shop_webhook\";b:1;s:17:\"read_shop_webhook\";b:1;s:19:\"delete_shop_webhook\";b:1;s:18:\"edit_shop_webhooks\";b:1;s:25:\"edit_others_shop_webhooks\";b:1;s:21:\"publish_shop_webhooks\";b:1;s:26:\"read_private_shop_webhooks\";b:1;s:20:\"delete_shop_webhooks\";b:1;s:28:\"delete_private_shop_webhooks\";b:1;s:30:\"delete_published_shop_webhooks\";b:1;s:27:\"delete_others_shop_webhooks\";b:1;s:26:\"edit_private_shop_webhooks\";b:1;s:28:\"edit_published_shop_webhooks\";b:1;s:25:\"manage_shop_webhook_terms\";b:1;s:23:\"edit_shop_webhook_terms\";b:1;s:25:\"delete_shop_webhook_terms\";b:1;s:25:\"assign_shop_webhook_terms\";b:1;}}s:15:\"shop_accountant\";a:2:{s:4:\"name\";s:15:\"Shop Accountant\";s:12:\"capabilities\";a:8:{s:4:\"read\";b:1;s:10:\"edit_posts\";b:0;s:12:\"delete_posts\";b:0;s:13:\"edit_products\";b:1;s:21:\"read_private_products\";b:1;s:17:\"view_shop_reports\";b:1;s:19:\"export_shop_reports\";b:1;s:18:\"edit_shop_payments\";b:1;}}s:11:\"shop_worker\";a:2:{s:4:\"name\";s:11:\"Shop Worker\";s:12:\"capabilities\";a:58:{s:4:\"read\";b:1;s:10:\"edit_posts\";b:0;s:12:\"upload_files\";b:1;s:12:\"delete_posts\";b:0;s:12:\"edit_product\";b:1;s:12:\"read_product\";b:1;s:14:\"delete_product\";b:1;s:13:\"edit_products\";b:1;s:20:\"edit_others_products\";b:1;s:16:\"publish_products\";b:1;s:21:\"read_private_products\";b:1;s:15:\"delete_products\";b:1;s:23:\"delete_private_products\";b:1;s:25:\"delete_published_products\";b:1;s:22:\"delete_others_products\";b:1;s:21:\"edit_private_products\";b:1;s:23:\"edit_published_products\";b:1;s:20:\"manage_product_terms\";b:1;s:18:\"edit_product_terms\";b:1;s:20:\"delete_product_terms\";b:1;s:20:\"assign_product_terms\";b:1;s:18:\"view_product_stats\";b:1;s:17:\"edit_shop_payment\";b:1;s:17:\"read_shop_payment\";b:1;s:19:\"delete_shop_payment\";b:1;s:18:\"edit_shop_payments\";b:1;s:25:\"edit_others_shop_payments\";b:1;s:21:\"publish_shop_payments\";b:1;s:26:\"read_private_shop_payments\";b:1;s:20:\"delete_shop_payments\";b:1;s:28:\"delete_private_shop_payments\";b:1;s:30:\"delete_published_shop_payments\";b:1;s:27:\"delete_others_shop_payments\";b:1;s:26:\"edit_private_shop_payments\";b:1;s:28:\"edit_published_shop_payments\";b:1;s:25:\"manage_shop_payment_terms\";b:1;s:23:\"edit_shop_payment_terms\";b:1;s:25:\"delete_shop_payment_terms\";b:1;s:25:\"assign_shop_payment_terms\";b:1;s:23:\"view_shop_payment_stats\";b:1;s:18:\"edit_shop_discount\";b:1;s:18:\"read_shop_discount\";b:1;s:20:\"delete_shop_discount\";b:1;s:19:\"edit_shop_discounts\";b:1;s:26:\"edit_others_shop_discounts\";b:1;s:22:\"publish_shop_discounts\";b:1;s:27:\"read_private_shop_discounts\";b:1;s:21:\"delete_shop_discounts\";b:1;s:29:\"delete_private_shop_discounts\";b:1;s:31:\"delete_published_shop_discounts\";b:1;s:28:\"delete_others_shop_discounts\";b:1;s:27:\"edit_private_shop_discounts\";b:1;s:29:\"edit_published_shop_discounts\";b:1;s:26:\"manage_shop_discount_terms\";b:1;s:24:\"edit_shop_discount_terms\";b:1;s:26:\"delete_shop_discount_terms\";b:1;s:26:\"assign_shop_discount_terms\";b:1;s:24:\"view_shop_discount_stats\";b:1;}}s:11:\"shop_vendor\";a:2:{s:4:\"name\";s:11:\"Shop Vendor\";s:12:\"capabilities\";a:11:{s:4:\"read\";b:1;s:10:\"edit_posts\";b:0;s:12:\"upload_files\";b:1;s:12:\"delete_posts\";b:0;s:12:\"edit_product\";b:1;s:13:\"edit_products\";b:1;s:14:\"delete_product\";b:1;s:15:\"delete_products\";b:1;s:16:\"publish_products\";b:1;s:23:\"edit_published_products\";b:1;s:20:\"assign_product_terms\";b:1;}}s:13:\"bbp_keymaster\";a:2:{s:4:\"name\";s:9:\"Keymaster\";s:12:\"capabilities\";a:0:{}}s:13:\"bbp_spectator\";a:2:{s:4:\"name\";s:9:\"Spectator\";s:12:\"capabilities\";a:0:{}}s:11:\"bbp_blocked\";a:2:{s:4:\"name\";s:7:\"Blocked\";s:12:\"capabilities\";a:0:{}}s:13:\"bbp_moderator\";a:2:{s:4:\"name\";s:9:\"Moderator\";s:12:\"capabilities\";a:0:{}}s:15:\"bbp_participant\";a:2:{s:4:\"name\";s:11:\"Participant\";s:12:\"capabilities\";a:0:{}}s:8:\"customer\";a:2:{s:4:\"name\";s:8:\"Customer\";s:12:\"capabilities\";a:1:{s:4:\"read\";b:1;}}s:16:\"nguoidangsanpham\";a:2:{s:4:\"name\";s:16:\"Nguoidangsanpham\";s:12:\"capabilities\";a:15:{s:13:\"edit_products\";b:1;s:20:\"edit_others_products\";b:1;s:16:\"publish_products\";b:1;s:23:\"edit_published_products\";b:1;s:21:\"edit_private_products\";b:1;s:17:\"manage_categories\";b:1;s:20:\"manage_product_terms\";b:1;s:18:\"edit_product_terms\";b:1;s:20:\"assign_product_terms\";b:1;s:15:\"delete_products\";b:1;s:22:\"delete_others_products\";b:1;s:25:\"delete_published_products\";b:1;s:23:\"delete_private_products\";b:1;s:20:\"delete_product_terms\";b:1;s:7:\"level_0\";b:1;}}s:15:\"frontend_vendor\";a:2:{s:4:\"name\";s:15:\"Frontend Vendor\";s:12:\"capabilities\";a:13:{s:4:\"read\";b:1;s:10:\"edit_posts\";b:1;s:12:\"upload_files\";b:1;s:12:\"edit_product\";b:1;s:12:\"read_product\";b:1;s:14:\"delete_product\";b:1;s:13:\"edit_products\";b:1;s:21:\"read_private_products\";b:1;s:21:\"edit_private_products\";b:1;s:20:\"manage_product_terms\";b:1;s:18:\"edit_product_terms\";b:1;s:20:\"assign_product_terms\";b:1;s:15:\"delete_products\";b:1;}}s:17:\"dc_pending_vendor\";a:2:{s:4:\"name\";s:14:\"Pending Vendor\";s:12:\"capabilities\";a:3:{s:4:\"read\";b:1;s:10:\"edit_posts\";b:0;s:12:\"delete_posts\";b:0;}}s:18:\"dc_rejected_vendor\";a:2:{s:4:\"name\";s:15:\"Rejected Vendor\";s:12:\"capabilities\";a:3:{s:4:\"read\";b:1;s:10:\"edit_posts\";b:0;s:12:\"delete_posts\";b:0;}}}' WHERE `option_name` = 'wp_user_roles';
```

it looks like option_values is very long.

And all the SQL like

```
UPDATE `wp_options` SET `option_value` = 'a:19:{s:13:\"administrator\";a:2:{s:4:\"name\";s:13:\"Administrator\";s:12:\"capabilities\"
```

So it is all about `'a:19:{s:13:\"administrator`

Could anybody please:

1. explain why the option_values is too long? It is normal, or a bug?
2. If it is a bug, how to solve it?
3. Is it something related to admin account of wordpress site?

Comment: check if there is index on the field  option_na . If not create one. the length is not very important.

Comment: thanks for helping. Do you mean option_name field?

Comment: yes there is a where clause in the update statement and this must found the row(s) for update. If there is no index they use a FULL TABLE SCAN, that means that they must read all row in the table to find the matching row -' WHERE `option_name` = 'wp_user_roles';

Comment: if you have a newer Version from MySQL MariaDB you can put EXPLAIN before yout UPDATE Statement to see if they use an index. in older versions it only works with SELECT. So you can also test it : EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM wp_options WHERE option_name = 'wp_user_roles';

Comment: this is what i get https://www.dropbox.com/s/5novaqi61u8lm7h/explain.JPG?dl=0

Comment: That looks ok. In the Column key is the name of the INDEX that used. Do you have add them ?

Comment: I am sorry, I do not understand your question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106812/discussion-between-bernd-buffen-and-john).

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box, the `option_value` column can store around 4GB, so it's not too small for the data you're trying to store there, which is around 20KB.

Comment: 4GB, see the documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-type-overview.html